# Localize Azure B2C error message 'A user with the specified credential could not be found' error message'

Tags: azure, localization, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am writing a custom policy for reset password on Azure B2C. When the user tries to reset password on an account that doesn't exist, this message shows up: 'A user with the specified credential could not be found' error message'.

As per the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization, I would like to localize this error message. Perhaps something like this:

```
<LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfVerificationFailedNoRetry">Some localized string</LocalizedString>
```

but in this case, the trouble is I don't know what the `StringId` of the error message is, and I can't find it anywhere in the documentation.

The error message does appear here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/error-codes, but how would one translate the error code to a StringId?

Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: error message on azure b2c showing 'A user with the specified credential could not be found']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

String ID

**UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist:**   We can't seem to find your account.

**forgotpassword_link** :                                            forgot password

For more string ID's Please refer  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids)

Comment: We have the `UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist` string localised already, and it shows up when the user tries to log in with a email that's not registered. 

However the same error message is not showing when we try to reset the password, in the forgot password journey. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: You need to apply the localisation to each contentDefinitionId. Most likely you are using different content definitions for the technical profiles for each scenario.